# How to make Git warn me about changing pushed commits?

Tags: git, warnings, git-commit, git-amend

tl;dr: Committing something, pushing that, amending that commit and trying to push again without using `--force` fails. How to set up Git so that it tells, when I try changing 'published commits'?

---

I am using Git for quite some time now and it still is one of the best things which ever happened to me (software-wise): it totally supports the way I do stuff out of the box. Just yesterday I did something stupid: I committed some stuff, pushed it to my remote, left the work for some minutes and when I came back, I noticed that I changed one of the files after I had added it, so that the commit was not complete. As usual, I used `git commit --amend` to fix this minor problem.

I worked on for several hours and decided that it was time for another `git push`. To my dismay, git refused to that and reading the message, scrolling back some thousand lines I saw what I did and knew what was going on. The remote basically is nothing more than a private off-site backup and nobody else uses it to push or pull. So I did not run into trouble with anybody rewriting history using `git push --force`. Since I would not like this to happen in a multi-user environment (either clean up my history or force-push) I thought about how to prevent this in future: Git could just issue a clearly visible warning, maybe even requiring me to type something. I'd notice and probably decide against amending.

So, the question is: how can I configure Git to warn me about amending commits which have already been pushed? Or more generally: how can I configure Git to warn me about changing published history?

**Edit #1 (~6 h later)**: Unfortunately, I do not feel confident enough to try to implement this on my own, but maybe it helps somebody to help me :) I thought that since `--amend` affects the latest commit only, it would suffice to have a pre-commit hook that checks the hash of the commit I am trying to amend and the current/latest commit pushed to the remote. For example currently I get `b45025a...` as the latest commit to master on my local machine, I pushed that and `cat .git/refs/remotes/<remote-name>/master` gives `b45025a...` as well. So, would it work to check if the corresponding remote branch is at the same commit as the one I am trying to amend right now?

---

Before writing this I asked Google and also briefly looked over questions I found here, but nothing seems to fit (selection):

- [How to undo "git commit --amend" done instead of "git commit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459150/how-to-undo-git-commit-amend-done-instead-of-git-commit)
- [git rebase interactive already pushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951719/git-rebase-interactive-already-pushed-commits)
- [Strategy for preventing or catching git history rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085871/strategy-for-preventing-or-catching-git-history-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a `post-rewrite` git-hook. This gets a list of rewritten commits on stdin which you could check against your remotes. Unfortunately this would just give you an error as there's no `pre-rewrite` hook.

edit: Someone challenged me to dust off my bash and give this one a try so here's a working warning:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Place this in the file .git/hooks/post-rewrite and make executable
#
# An attempt to write a git-hook to warn of rewritten commits on remotes

while read -r commit junk; do
  if [ ! -z "$(git branch -r --contains $commit)" ]; then
    echo "############################### WARNING ###############################"
    echo "$commit has been rebased but exists on these remote branches"
    echo $(git branch -r --contains $commit)
    echo "You may want to rethink this rewrite"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Since I am concerned with amending (and that only applies to the last commit, right?), wouldn't a pre-commit hook might work? I added some more thoughts to the question. Thank you for your efforts! :D

Comment: From git-scm.com "This hook is invoked by commands that rewrite commits (git commit --amend, git-rebase; currently git-filter-branch does not call it!)". So this hook will catch amends and warn you. If you want to abort the commit you would indeed need to do a pre-commit hook and to do `exit -1` if you can figure a way to detect it.

Comment: Also you can test whether the latest commit exists on a remote branch with `git branch -r --contains $(git show --no-patch --format=%H HEAD)` but the difficulty is figuring out what operation you're currently doing as this on its own catches regular commits as well as amends.